# Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteURI) Clearing all user entries

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page where a user fills in some text boxes which get saved to a SQL database using a Submit button.  The page also contains a button that allows them to upload attachments.  If the user uploads an attachment BEFORE clicking the submit button to save the other data, the values in the text boxes are cleared once the upload routine executes the Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).  I have tried saving the values I want to restore into the Session, but I don't seem to be able to restore them.  The debugger shows they are there, but once the Response.Redirect is executed, the next lines are never executed.  I'm brand new to ASP.NET, so I may just be missing something obvious.  Here is the code for the upload procedure:

```
Protected Sub Upload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Session("Phone") = txtPhone.Text
    Session("Name") = txtName.Text
    Session("Email") = txtEmail.Text
    Session("StartDate") = txtStartDate.Text
    Session("EndDate") = txtEndDate.Text
    Session("Subject") = txtSubject.Text
    Session("Description") = txtDescription.Value
    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim contentType As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
    Using fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
        Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
            Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("EngineeringRequestsConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Dim query As String = "insert into Attachments values (@id, @Name, @ContentType, @Data)"
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nextId
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = contentType
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    hasUpload = True
    Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    BindGrid()

End Sub
```

The BindGrid() procedure attempts to restore the values from Session but never gets executed.

```
If hasUpload Then
        txtPhone.Text = CType(Session("Phone"), String)
        txtName.Text = CType(Session("Name"), String)
        txtStartDate.Text = CType(Session("StartDate"), String)
End If
```

This is my first post on SO. I apologize if in advance if it is not clear enough.

Comment: well if you redirect to another page, then obviously the following code will never execute (or at least, the results will never be seen), because the new page you're redirecting to gets executed and sent to the browser instead. What else did you expect? Even if your redirection goes to the _same page_, it creates a _new refresh_ of that page, and starts executing from the page_load event as if the previous execution context never happened. I don't think you need to redirect. If you just let the page finish you'll end up with the grid bound ok. Maybe you need to study the ASP.NET page lifecycle

Comment: As I said, I'm brand new to ASP.NET and trying to get my head wrapped around the behaviors.  I'll try removing the redirect and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to ASP.NET webforms it's probably worth checking out the [Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) as this dictates the order in which events are fired when a page is loaded. The issue is that you are effectively taking the user from page A to page B but expecting them to see results on page A.

In your method

```
Protected Sub Upload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
  .. skip ..
  Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
  BindGrid()
```

When you call `Response.Redirect()` the browser will redirect to a new page (e.g. from A -> B), this will start the page lifecycle over again, anything that happens after `Response.Redirect()` won't be rendered. I think what is confusing you is that you are redirecting from (A -> A), however this will still cause the page to be reloaded.

One option is to call `BindGrid()` and reload the data from session in one of the page load events, or remove the call to `Response.Redirect()` all together and instead leave the page as-is.

Comment: Thank you!  That got me the information I needed to get this working.  Being brand new here, it will not let me upvote this.

Comment: Yup, missed that option at first.  Got it now.